# Generating test data for unit test cases for nested objects

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

When mocking dependent services for writing unit test cases for any enterprise-grade java service, I find setting up the data for the unit test cases a huge pain. Most of the times, this is the single most compelling reason for developers to not write unit test cases and rather write integration style test cases. If the service is dependent on couple of other services (which depend on their respective DAO's) and a DAO of its own, generating the `when-thenReturn` clauses for a reasonably nested object becomes quite an effort and developers are seen to be taking the easy route and loading the entire spring context and sourcing their data from the direct sources which may not always give the data that can traverse all required code paths. With this in the background, a colleague of mine suggested that why not run a sample integration test, and using aspects, capture all of the relevant data points and serialize it to an XML representation which may be used for materializing test data for the unit test cases. To our pleasant surprise we found a framework called [TestDataCaptureJ on github](https://github.com/davidwong/TestDataCaptureJ) which was very similar to this. It used aspects to capture the data points and it generated the java code to create the objects.

The [motivation](http://www.davidwong.com.au/TestDataCaptureJ/#d0e51) stated on the site seemed very apt and I was wondering if there are any other alternatives that can give similar features. Also, it would be great if the experts can critique this overall approach.

Also, the project is about 2 yrs old and has a few bugs which we we had to fix and are hoping to give it back as a mavenized github fork. Just checking to ensure that there is no other similar initiative from one of the well-known stables as well.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Interesting! I learn something new on stackoverflow everyday! It's more like stackneveroverflow with the amount of things you can learn :D.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have two *critiques* to that approach... and please bear in mind that my knowledge of your context is almost nil, which means that what I suggest here might not work for you.

I've only once experienced a problem like the one you mentioned, and it was a symptom that there was too much coupling between the objects because the responsbilities were **way** to broad. Since then I use a [Domain-Driven Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) approach and I haven't had this problem again.

I prefer to use [Test-Data Builders](http://www.natpryce.com/articles/000714.html) to create test data. This approach allows me to have a template of what I want to build, and just replace the bits I'm interested in the test. If you decide to go this way, I strongly suggest you to use a tiny library called [Make-It-Easy](http://code.google.com/p/make-it-easy/) that simplifies the creation of these builders.

#### And two suggestions

If you have some time, I suggest you to

1. Watch a presetation called [The Deep Synergy Between Testability and Good Design](http://vimeo.com/15007792) by Michael Feathers - Part of the talk is about something very similar to what you're experiencing.
2. Read the book [Growing Object-Orieted Systems, Guided by Tests](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321503627) (aka GOOS), it has all sorts of insights about how to write simple, amazing, testable code.

Comment: Thanks of the information - will review the links and see how this fits in!