# How can I create one data provider that can be used through the test suite?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, testng

I have an application where one project can take 20 minutes to run. This is because I have to emulate creating a plethora of objects that rely on other objects which in turn rely on a different set of objects. For example, I want to test a Messaging class. However, a Message may rely on a User or their Permissions. And as such I want to recreate a scenario where I have 10000 Messages assigned to 500 Users with a different number of Permissions, which means they may or may not be able to see it.

I have a number of ControllerTests that test this kind of things by creating thousands of objects each time a ControllerTest is started up. As it's doing it manually and connecting to the database each time it takes up a lot of time.

Is there a certain way to do this once through the application or a specific package or a project? I want to test a package that has 100 Controller test cases but I want to create these objects once and provide it to them as needed.

I am using TestNg and Spring.

Comment: Please take a look to http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-unit-testing/database-test-data-creation.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568742/generating-test-data-for-unit-test-cases-for-nested-objects and for sample java data generator http://codearte.github.io/jfairy/

Comment: Would it be possible to pass in different object types e.g. Message, User, Permission? All the examples I've seen on the internet only pass one object type.

Comment: jfairy seems a generic solution, is it handle your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

TestNG's @Dataprovider supports any objects: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders

but still if you have to create very big graph many times it might be easier to create it once and make it immutable.

Answer (score 0):

Doing it once through the application, you can try implementing the [ISuiteListener](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/ISuiteListener.html) onStart method.  This would ensure that your setup happens once.  You might put in some parallel running code to speed up the process as well.

If you want to do specific setup for a package.  You can look at [ITestListener](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/ITestListener.html) onStart method.  When you run, add the package to your `<test>`

Alternatively, based on your problem statement, I am not sure if you are looking for a dataprovider, since you would like your setup to run just once.  In the below solution, it would be run once for each test.

But if you do want to share a dataprovider between classes, then you can put it in a single class.  It needs to be a static method and you specify the class where it can be found in the dataProviderClass attribute: (sample below from [testng doc](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders))

```
public class MyTest {
  @Test(dataProvider = "create", dataProviderClass = StaticProvider.class)
  public void test(Integer n) {
    // ...
  }
}
```